# What's a good way to set up Closure Compiler on Linux? Or, where should Java .jar's live on a Linux?

Tags: java, linux, unix, libraries, google-closure-compiler

I'd like to set up a process where I can generate minified and optimized JS for my webapps as part of the process of pushing updated code to the webserver with git.

It's quite straightforward to run it: `java -jar ./compiler.jar script.js`

Of course if I have ten projects I don't want ten `compiler.jar`s.

If I stick it here: `/usr/local/lib/compiler.jar` my call just looks stupid:

```
java -jar /usr/local/lib/compiler.jar script.js
```

It would make more sense to dump it in `~` like I do with everything else that doesn't have a place to go. It just feels sloppy.

Is there some directory that I can stick my jars into so that I can run them more easily, rather than my having to set up (symlinks to) shell scripts (or possibly better, shell command aliases) for each jar I want to use?

For example, shouldn't there be a system where I put my jar in a global designated java lib directory, after which point I may call `java closure script.js`?

**Edit:** I tried putting it in `jre/lib/ext` which I found here, but it did not work:

```
$ find /usr/lib | grep jre/lib/ext                         
/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.7.0-openjdk-1.7.0.25.x86_64/jre/lib/ext
.... bunch of other jar files here
$ cp ~/compiler.jar /usr/lib/jvm/java-1.7.0-openjdk-1.7.0.25.x86_64/jre/lib/ext
$ java -jar compiler.jar script.js
Error: Unable to access jarfile compiler.jar
```

Comment: I'm starting to think that maybe I'm supposed to keep the jar with every project. ಠ_ಠ

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My answer is more a suggestion that you do not reinvent the wheel, and that hopefully will save you from problems, you did not run in - yet, since you were already suggesting in your own comment that it might be good to include the jar in every project. :-)

I would suggest putting the jar in every project and make it self contained or better: run a setup script in every project, which fetches the jar from a remote location.

You could script the setup script by hand or go one step further and use a task runner, to create your own build-toolchain, which you can reuse on multiple projects.

We transitioned our project structure to `Grunt` tasks (http://gruntjs.com) Grunt contains a closure-compiler plugin (and many more plugins, e.g. `sass`). Each project contains a Grunt config file, which specifies all tasks, e.g. test, build, which you can invoke on the given project. So you have to install Grunt once on your machine and Grunt will pick up all your tasks for a given project and will take care of downloading the closure-compiler.jar and invoking the closure-compiler.

So even, if you might think right now: "I only need the closure-compiler" eventually you might need another tool `B` and start bash-scripting for tool `B`. I suggest you invest more time in learning, for example Grunt, and use the work of the community.

A side note: Before we used `Grunt` I set up the build-toolchain with another taskrunner, `Gradle` (http://www.gradle.org), which is popular for `Java` projects, motivated by the fact that the closure-compiler.jar is itself a Java project. This worked quite nice but I finally noticed that there is more Web-Project-Based support for Grunt than Gradle. As I believe in the right tool for the right job, my conclusion is: use Grunt for Javascript-Projects, Gradle for Java/JVM.

Comment: Thanks, this looks like a good way to get around inventing a few wheels

Comment: I was originally starting to set up a shell script or makefile system for doing "compilation style" tasks, so that when I commit code it will also include generated code. Grunt appears to exactly fill this type of role.

Comment: Here appear to be the specific directions for obtaining a good clean installation of closure-compiler, for use with e.g. grunt-closure-compiler: https://github.com/gmarty/grunt-closure-compiler#closure-compiler-installation-from-source  However it's probably smartest to just grab the jar download. At least this does not require having a copy of the jar for each project.

Comment: Holy Batman! Grunt is next to impossible to debug (as I do not have a node debugging environment configured yet). A lot of these node tools are sadly quite lacking in quality (but node itself is pretty good about that). All of this wild goose chasing on why my gruntfile dies with a mysterious unhelpful warning isn't helping to sell this workflow. I could give you like 5 reasons why shell scripts are superior right about now. You see, with grunt plugins there is this mysterious trend of conflicting and arbitrary ways of indirecting function calls with nested JS object structures. This is EVIL!

Comment: @Jan Weitz can you add a reference to the closure compiler plugin from grunt that downloads the compiler jar? I came across several plugins, but all of them had one issue or another. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I would also put it in each and every project. This is to make them self-contained. Here is my code to do so:

```
cd /path/to/your/project
sudo apt-get install -y default-jre
wget "https://dl.google.com/closure-compiler/compiler-latest.tar.gz"
tar -xf compiler-latest.tar.gz
rm compiler-latest.tar.gz README.md COPYING
mv closure-compiler* closure-compiler.jar # rename for easier use
```

Answer (score 1):

### What's a good way to set up Closure Compiler on Linux?

It depends on you Linux distribution. Typically, it is already available in package repositories.

E.g. for CentOS 7, you would run:

```
yum install https://extras.getpagespeed.com/release-el7-latest.rpm
yum install closure-compiler
```

Then simply invoke it via `closure-compiler <arguments>`

If you don't use a distro that packaged it, see next answer.

### Or, where should Java .jar's live on a Linux?

The system packages for `.jar` files typically go into `/usr/share/java/` (at least so in RedHat based systems). Additionally, manually installed or downloaded software should go into `/usr/local` according to FHS standards.

From the above, you can decipher that `/usr/local/share/java/` should be a proper place to put your manually downloaded `.jar` files if you want to have them accessible to multiple users / projects.

Answer (score 0):

If you using the java command directly, then you'll have to provide a path to the jar in question. It's probably easier to place the jar in one place and create a shell script that handles the invocation and jar path.

Answer (score 0):

I use an **alias** which I think is much more efficient than having a shell script sitting somewhere achieving roughly the same thing.

```
alias closure='java -jar /opt/closure-compiler/compiler.jar'
```

In use:

```
closure --js i.js --js_output_file i.min.js
```